# Adding new places in google maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, web

I am using [Google javascript api](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial?hl=fr) Currently. I would like to add new places like add small villages in the map, these small village does not appear in google map even when I am highest zoom. I know villages Lat/Lang and would like to add them when someone zoom in map (placed in my website). I can use Marker to accomplish similar, But it is not same as having places by default appear on map.

I tried searching stackoverflow and elsehere on net, But could not find any references. If someone can please sugggest on it

Answer (score 0):

You need to request it from google: [google.com/mapmaker](http://google.com/mapmaker) 
You need to drew a polygon of the city borders.

**every request must to be approved by google.**

[image: Example Here]

Hope its help.

Answer (score 0):

I used MarkWithLabel to accompalish http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/tags/markerwithlabel/1.1.8/docs/examples.html